# Cannot install react-native

Tags: react-native, npm, installation, error-handling

I want to learn React Native but I cannot figure out how to install it. It gives me this error message.

command: npm install -g expo-cli //installing react-native?
error: npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install node? It seems that npm is not installed on your machine, which comes with node. [Here is the link to the download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)